# MySQL convert latin1 encoded to utf8

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table which `utf8_general_ci` is encoded, but by an error, `the records were written incorrectly in the database in latin1`. How can I convert all records to `utf8`? The problem is namely the special characters such as "`ä`, `ü`, `ö`" etc.

Comment: What software gave you the error "the records were written incorrectly in the database in latin1"? That seems odd. If the characters WERE unicode, but were written to disk as ASCII or some lesser-than-unicode form, then there is no recovering it back to a UNICODE character. Latin/Ascii stores in a single byte, but UTF8 stores in 3 bytes (pre 5.5) or 4 bytes (post-5.5). You have lost 2-3 bytes of information per character.

Comment: no software issues this error, the problem is that the records are displayed incorrectly in the database. I want these to be displayed correctly there